# Updating missing values in one table based on values in another

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to accomplish something that seems very straight forward but I can't seem to figure it out.  I have two stand alone tables.  The first is an output report containing a field of land use codes.  The other is a lookup table containing definitions of those codes.  I need to update a field in the lookup table with any codes that are present in the report but missing in the lookup table.  See Code below.  I am getting stuck on trying to retrieve the values from the search cursor.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
import csv, arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

table = "S:\\Zone_GP_Update\\Zoning.gdb\\CrystalReportViewer"
field = "Gen_Plan_Primary"
table2 = "S:\\Zone_GP_Update\\Zoning.gdb\\GenPlanLU"
field2 = "LANDUSECOD"
companyList = []


with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table,field)as cursor:
    companyList = [row for row in cursor]

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(table2,field2) as tablecursor:
    for tablerow in tablecursor:
        if tablerow[0] in companyList:
            continue
        else:
            tablerow[1] = row.getValue(field)
        cursor.insertRow(tablerow)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].

Comment: companyList = [row[0] for row in cursor], from there you need another search cursor, not an insert cursor, to find the values in table2,field2 that aren't in companyList (addList = [] if row[0] not in companyList: addList.append(row[0])) *then* an insert cursor to insert the values in addList.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break this down into three steps:

1. Find the values you already have, and insert into a list.
2. Find the values from table 2 that aren't already in the list of existing values, compile these values into a new list of values to add.
3. Insert the new values into the table.

You're most of the way there, have a look at this code and see if it helps.

```
import arcpy
# import pythonaddins   ##Not used
# import csv, arcpy, os ##Not used, arcpy already imported
# from arcpy import env ##Not used

table = "S:\\Zone_GP_Update\\Zoning.gdb\\CrystalReportViewer"
field = "Gen_Plan_Primary"
table2 = "S:\\Zone_GP_Update\\Zoning.gdb\\GenPlanLU"
field2 = "LANDUSECOD"
# companyList = [] ## not needed


with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table,field)as cursor:
        companyList = [row[0] for row in cursor] # need to use the value not the object

addList = [] # empty list for the unmatched values

# find the values that aren't in the companyList
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table2,field2) as tablecursor:
        for tableRow in tablecursor:
                if tableRow[0] not in companyList:
                        if tableRow[0] not in addList: # don't add duplicates
                        addList.append(tableRow[0])    # add to the empty list for those that aren't there already

# insert the non-matching values into table 
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(table,field) as insCursor:
        for thisValue in addList:
                insCursor.insertRow([thisValue])
```

On the last line of your code you're calling `cursor.insertRow(tablerow)` but `cursor` isn't defined (you're outside the `with` block) - you should get an error here.

Please note that python is a case sensitive language, 'grass' != 'Grass', so you might want to do your comparisons in either [upper](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_upper.htm)() or lower() case.. change the appropriate lines: `companyList = [row[0].lower() for row in cursor]` then `if tableRow[0].lower() not in companyList:` to protect yourself against case problems. [Trimming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-do-i-trim-whitespace) can also help.

Although not totally necessary, it's a good idea when creating your existing value list to only insert each value once, it will speed up later processing if you populate the existing value list thus:

```
companyList = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table,field)as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] not in companyList:
            companyList.append(row[0]) # need to use the value not the object
```

Comment: Thank you Michael.  That did the trick wonderfully and you comments were extremely helpful.  Thanks